# Make a column in a row show vertical scroll bar if it does not fit on the screen

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Expanding this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-height-of-the-remaining-screen-space) on stackoverflow.

What to modify in the CSS to make the `col2` show scroll bar when the space is constrained vertically to the point it does not fit on the screen? Currently the scroll bar is displayed for the entire page.

HTML and CSS:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.box .row.header {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

.box .row.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

#col1 { 
  flex: 0 1 50px;
  background: lightgreen;
}

#col2 { 
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow: auto;
  background: lightblue;
}

.box .row.footer {
  flex: 0 1 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="row header">
    <p><b>header</b>
      <br />
      <br />(sized to content)</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row content">
    <div id="col1" class="col">col 1</div>
    <div id="col2" class="col">
      <p>col 2</p>
      <p>col 2</p>
      <p>col 2</p>
      <p>col 2</p>
      <p>col 2</p>
      <p>col 2</p>
      <p>col 2</p>
      <p>col 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>  
  <div class="row footer">
    <p><b>footer</b> (fixed height)</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This example is also here: https://jsfiddle.net/0ejLg25m/10/

Comment: In order to generate a scrollbar, you need an overflow condition. But if you have the height of the element set to `auto`, meaning that the element will stretch / shrink based on content size, there will never be an overflow. You need a hard limit somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

flex items have a min width/height equal to content, this will prevent the scrollbars because the parent will grow to fit the content.

In this case it's the height so we need to apply `min-height:0;` on the parent of `col2`.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.box .row.header {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

.box .row.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  min-height: 0;
}

#col1 {
  flex: 0 1 50px;
  background: lightgreen;
}

#col2 {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow: auto;
  background: lightblue;
}

.box .row.footer {
  flex: 0 1 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="row header">
    <p><b>header</b>
      <br />
      <br />(sized to content)</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row content">
    <div id="col1" class="col">col 1</div>
    <div id="col2" class="col">
      <p>col 2</p>
      <p>col 2</p>
      <p>col 2</p>
      <p>col 2</p>
      <p>col 2</p>
      <p>col 2</p>
      <p>col 2</p>
      <p>col 2</p>
      <p>col 2</p>
      <p>col 2</p>
      <p>col 2</p>
      <p>col 2</p>
      <p>col 2</p>
      <p>col 2</p>
      <p>col 2</p>
      <p>col 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row footer">
    <p><b>footer</b> (fixed height)</p>
  </div>
</div>
```